# Confidence Intervals of ROC Curve's AUCs overlap but delong test is significant?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, roc, auc

I am using ci.auc in the pROC library to calculate AUC's confidence intervals and roc.test to calculate delong test.

When I run the following:

```
ci.auc(roc1, conf.level=0.95) 
ci.auc(roc2, conf.level=0.95)
roc.test(roc1, roc2, method = "delong", conf.level=0.95)
```

I get the following:

AUC of ROC 1: 0.5769568 (95% CI 0.5654099 - 0.5885037 )

AUC of ROC 2: 0.5566634 (95% CI 0.5463438 - 0.5669831)

DeLong test p value is 0.003559239

**If the confidence intervals overlap why is the delong test significant?**

Answer (score 1):

Non-overlapping confidence intervals is a much higher standard than zero not being in the confidence interval for the difference between two parameters. This applies all over in statistics, not just for this particular situation.

In this particular case, think about it this way: AUC1 is not in the confidence interval for AUC2, and AUC2 is not in the confidence interval for AUC1. Each of those confidence intervals is telling you that the other AUC is not a plausible value. Thus, the AUCs must be different, hence the small p-value when you formally test for equality.

**EDIT**

This simulation isn't about ROCAUC, but it does show that there can be a significant difference despite overlapping confidence intervals.

```r
set.seed(2023)
N1 <- 10
N2 <- N1
alpha <- 0.05
R <- 10000
reject_with_ci_overlap <- rep(0, R)
for (i in 1:R){
  
  # Simulate data
  #
  x1 <- rnorm(N1, 0, 1)
  x2 <- rnorm(N2, 0.5, 1)

  # Set trackers of conditions being met
  #
  tracker_overlap <- 0
  tracker_psignif <- 0
  
  # Determine confidence intervals for each mean
  #
  ci1 <- t.test(x1, conf.level = 1 - alpha)$conf.int
  ci2 <- t.test(x2, conf.level = 1 - alpha)$conf.int
  
  # Check if the confidence intervals overlap
  #
  if (
    ci1[2] <= ci2[2] # Is the upper limit of ci2 above the upper limit of ci1?
    & 
    ci1[2] >= ci2[1] # Is the upper limit of ci1 above the lower limit of ci2?
    ){
    tracker_overlap <- tracker_overlap + 1 # Then there is overlap
  }
  if (
    ci2[2] <= ci1[2] # Is the upper limit of ci1 above the upper limit of ci2?
    & 
    ci2[2] >= ci1[1] # Is the upper limit of ci2 above the lower limit of ci1?
    ){
    tracker_overlap <- tracker_overlap + 1 # Then there is overlap
  }
  
  # Check if the two-sample t-test p-value is below alpha
  #
  if (t.test(x1, x2, var.equal = F)$p.value <= alpha){
    tracker_psignif <- 1
  }
  
  # Check if both conditions are met; if so, put a 1 in place i 
  # of reject_with_ci_overlap
  #
  if (tracker_overlap > 0 & tracker_psignif > 0){
    reject_with_ci_overlap[i] <- 1
  }
  
  # Print progress
  #
  if (i %% 1000 == 0 | i < 5){
    print(paste(
      round(i/R*100, 2), "% complete",
      sep = ""
    ))
  }
}

# Calculate the percentage of iterations where confidence intervals overlap
# yet the two-sample test rejects the null
#
mean(reject_with_ci_overlap) * 100 # 14.19%
```

I get this behavior in $14.19\%$ of the iterations, so this is far from unusual.

Comment: However, it is the opposite way around the confidence intervals do overlap. The upper 95% confidence interval for AUC 2 is 0.5669831 and the lower 95% confidence interval for AUC 1 is 0.5654099.

Comment: @Eddie Again, non-overlapping confidence intervals is not necessary for the difference to be significantly different from zero.